# Error using active contour

Tags: image, matlab, image-segmentation

I got an error when using active contour:

> ??? Undefined function or method 'activecontour' for input
>   arguments of type 'single'.
>
> Error in ==> Segmentasi>threshold_Callback at 114
>   final = activecontour(image2,mask , 100);

```
image1 = handles.citra1;
    level=0.008;
    bw = edge(image1,'Canny');
    axes(handles.axes2);
    imshow(bw,[]);

    %active contour
    image2 = bwdist(~bw);
    mask = zeros(size(image2));
    mask(25:end-25,25:end-25) = 1;
    final = activecontour(image2,mask , 100);
    axes(handles.axes5)
    imshow(final,[]);
    handles.data3 = final;
    guidata(hObject,handles);
```

I am using an image from dicom files (sagital image)

Comment: thanks adriaan for editing my question :)

Comment: `activecontour` was introduced into MATLAB's CVST toolbox as of MATLAB R2013a.  Which version of MATLAB do you have?  If you have anything prior to R2013a then you won't have this function and that's why you're getting this error.  See the documentation for more details... specifically all the way at the bottom.  You'll see when the function was introduced: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/activecontour.html

Comment: oh ic, im using matlab 2011a thats why i cant use this function, thanks for solving my problem, :)

Answer (score 3):

The problim is that the output of the `bwdist` function is a matrix and the input of the `activecontour` function is a grayscale image. So you need to convert the matrix to a grayscale image before using it. This is done using a function called `mat2gray`. To do so, after using `bwdist` apply `mat2gray` as follows:

```
image2 = mat2gray(bwdist(~bw));
```

And then the rest of the code works. Check my simple example:

```
bw = zeros(200,200);
bw(50,50) = 1;
bw(50,150) = 1;
bw(150,50) = 1;
D1 = bwdist(bw);

D2 = mat2gray(D1);
mask = zeros(size(D2));
mask(25:end-25,25:end-25) = 1;
final = activecontour(D2,mask,100);

subplot(1,3,1);imshow(bw)
subplot(1,3,2);imshow(mat2gray(D1))
subplot(1,3,3);imshow(final,[]);
```

[image]

Comment: i have try your code, but now its say 

_"Undefined function or method 'activecontour' for input
arguments of type 'double'."_

Comment: @alandsamuel Can you post an image? Because as you can see this method is supposed to work as I have shown.

Comment: @NKN The OP doesn't have the `activecontour` function. This is the only explanation for their problem if you've written a solution and it works.

Comment: its solved, i cant use activecontour function because, i'm using 2011a matlab, and activecontour function is introduced in matlab 2013, btw thanks for helping :)

Comment: If I could provide a minor comment, accepting this answer is questionable because this actually didn't solve your problem. This sends the incorrect message. Though I appreciate NKN's efforts and I surely don't want to be an influence on lost reputation, this isn't the right answer... but it does provide some nice tips on the use of the function. I'll leave it to your discretion.